# Center cursor in form field

Tags: html, forms, css, webforms

I'm looking for a way to **center** the cursor and the text inputted into a form field, just like the search field at WIRED's homepage: https://www.wired.com/

[Wired's search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is3eg.png)

Thank you for your help already

Comment: input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
}

Comment: Hey, you are a god and I am really really dumb.

Comment: position: absolute;
    text-align: center;

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center;` to the inputs' CSS rule.
This works the same as centering text on a webpage.

`input[type="text"] {
    text-align:center;
}`